# Convert the results of np.argsort() to tuple

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 10x10 array filled with floats and would like to get the indices which would sort that array and put them into an array or list of tuples. For a smaller example I have:

```
A = [[0,1,2],[4,9,3],[5,8,7]]
```

(not 10x10 but it's just for an example)

and then I would want to create:

```
ind = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(1,0),(2,0),(2,2),(2,1),(1,1)]
```

right now I tried

```
ind = np.argsort(A,axis=0)
```

which gives something like

```
ind = [0 1 2 12 10 20 22 21 11]
```

the ultimate goal is to be able to do

```
A[ind[i]]
```

and get the ith smallest number

Comment: You are probably want to flatten the array first. The following might help you: `min_element = A.ravel()[np.argsort(A.ravel())][0]`, `max_element = A.ravel()[np.argsort(A.ravel())][-1]`

Comment: No, I want to keep A as 2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [55]: A = np.array([[0,1,2],[4,9,3],[5,8,7]])
```

`argsort` with axis `None` to sort the whole thing:

```
In [56]: idx=np.argsort(A,None)                                                 
In [57]: idx                                                                    
Out[57]: array([0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 8, 7, 4])
```

There are indices in the flat or raveled form of A

```
In [58]: A.flat[idx]                                                            
Out[58]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9])
```

3nd smallest:

```
In [59]: A.flat[idx[2]]                                                         
Out[59]: 2
```

We can get 2d indices with:

```
In [60]: np.unravel_index(idx,A.shape)                                          
Out[60]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1]))
```

I believe these values match your desired set of indices - but I have to convert them to tuple to do the indexing:

```
In [61]: np.transpose(np.unravel_index(idx,A.shape))                            
Out[61]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 1]])
In [63]: A[tuple(_61[2])]                                                       
Out[63]: 2
```